# How come Python 3 deserializes json files so fast?

Tags: python, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

Recently, I had to `json.load()` a file. A 13,045KB file from a network location. Over a slow corporate VPN. I did it in an interactive shell and decided to go grab a coffee in the meantime, because this would surely take ages to load. I didn't even manage do stand up and my code was done reading the json and translating its half milion lines into a beautiful dictionary.

How does it happen that Python is able to do it so efficiently? What optimizations are used? Why does it take a few minutes for Sublime to show this json as a text?

```py
>>> f_path = r"Z:\some\network\location\data.json"
>>> import os
>>> os.stat(f_path).st_size
13357297
>>> with measurement_tools.SimpleBenchmark():
...     with open(f_path) as f:
...       t_dict = json.load(f)        
Took 0.203125 seconds.
```

Edit: SimpleBenchmark() is just my own context manager measuring tool doing basically `t1-t0`.

Edit 2: since there were questions about why I consider it fast, I compared it to serializing the same dictionary into a json in the same location which took c.a. 10 times as much time (well over 2 secs).

Comment: Fast compared to what?

Comment: As mentioned in the questions, for example, to Sublime reading it as text.

Comment: This isn't particularly fast, and about what I'd expect. You can't use how long it takes sublime to render it, it's an apples to oranges comparison. It's meaningless. Note, the json library is written in C

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I didn't know that json module is implemented in C. Please see my edit 2 - we can compare it to serializing.

Comment: As a side note, [ujson](https://pypi.org/project/ujson/) would be even faster in case you have the need for it.

Comment: Thanks @Darkonaut, never heard of ujson.